# Flyway SQL directory not found while migrating from within a war

Tags: flyway

**Environment**

- Jboss 6
- flyway 1.5
- spring core 2.5.6

**structure of the war**

```
ei-web-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
    |WEB-INF
      |classes
        |db
          |migrations
            |ei
              |V5.7.0.sql
              |V5.7.1.sql
              |V5.7.2.sql
```

**The problem**

When I try to execute the Flyway migrations inside a MBean loaded at the startup of my JBoss I get the following stack trace.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [vfs:/C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/ei/deploy/ei-web-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/db/migrations/ei/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:/C:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/ei/deploy/ei-web-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/db/migrations/ei/

**Clues**

- The flyway base dir is *db/migrations/ei*
- The flyway initial version is *5.7.0*
- When launched in a standalone way, migrations are OK
- IMHO, the problem is the consequence of the unsuccessful scan of the classpath directory.

See [com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.sql.SqlMigrationResolver (L.99)](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/source/browse/flyway-core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/flyway/core/migration/sql/SqlMigrationResolver.java?name=flyway-parent-1.5)

```
final String searchPattern = "**/" + sqlMigrationPrefix + "?*" + sqlMigrationSuffix;
Resource[] resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classLoader)
                .getResources("classpath:" + searchRoot + searchPattern);
```

In my case, resources returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the same issue as https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/91

Feel free to cast your vote :-)